# PCI Graphics Card prevents post

Tags: graphics-card, pci, intel-atom

I bought a Quadro4 400 NVS (4 screen) PCI Graphics card many years ago and still works in every computer i try but not my new one.

My new pc is a Intel Atom D525MW with 4GB of ram.

As soon as i install it, the pc refuses to Post (nothing on any of the displays, or from the on-board graphics), if i change the BIOS setting to only use onboard graphics, it still will not boot.

I have tryed disabling everything in the BIOS, serial, USB, onboard sound, ect. Then installed the card and it still Wouldnt boot

I tryed my 1000watt Psu from last PC to see if it was a psu issue, same problem

As the board only has 1 PCI slot, i cannot try my Post Card, and i dont have a Mini-Pcie tester

If i install another old PCI Gpu (like S3 or ati rage) it works fine.

Can any one think of anything to try, or time to give up

Comment: Is there a secondary power socket on the card? Given the number of outputs I would expect there to be one. If you haven't plugged that in it might explain the problem.

Comment: Sorry there isnt An external power socket on the card, it draws all the power from PCI slot

Comment: Something wrong with the PCI slot then? Try another Graphics card in it.

Comment: Not all the PCI slots work at the same voltage. Old devices used to be 5V, but more recent devices use 3.5V Check the voltage requirements of your card and the specs of your Atom motherboard.